# Bilinear form properties

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us look at: $B:V\times W$ be a bilinear form.

$T_{B} : W \to V^{*}$

$(T_{B}(w))(v) = B(v, w)$

and

$S_{B} : V \to W^{*}$

$(S_{B}(v))(w)=B(v,w)$

I need to prove that:

$\operatorname{rank}(B) = \dim\operatorname{Im}(S_{B}) = \dim\operatorname{Im}(T_{B})$

So how can I do that ?

All I know is that $B$ can the matrix represent according to some basis is:

\begin{pmatrix}
  I_{r} & 0\\
  0 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}

meaning the rank of $B$ is $r$ but how can I continue from here in order to calculate $\dim\operatorname{Im}(S_{B})$ and $\dim\operatorname{Im}(T_{B})$?

Answer (score 1):

So let $\mathcal B_V = \{v_1, \ldots, v_m\}$, $\mathcal B_W = \{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ be bases of $V$ and $W$. Then we can represent $B$ by a matrix $(b_{ij})$, where $b_{ij} = B(v_i, w_j)$. Corresponding to $\mathcal B_V$ and $\mathcal B_W$ we have the dual bases $\mathcal B_V^* = \{v_1^*, \ldots, v_m^*\}$ and $\mathcal B_W^* = \{w_1^*,\ldots, w_n^*\}$ of $V^*$ and $W^*$ respectively, given by 
$$ w_i^*(w_j) = \delta_{ij}, \quad v_i^*(v_j) = \delta_{ij} $$
Let us now compute the matrix $[T_B]_{\mathcal B_W, \mathcal B_V^*}$ of $T_B$ in the bases $\mathcal B_W$ and $\mathcal B_V^*$. Let $1 \le i \le n$, write $T_B w_i = \sum_k \alpha_{ik} v_k^*$. We have for $1 \le j \le m$:
\begin{align*}
  \alpha_{ij} &= \sum_{k} \alpha_{ik} v_k^*(v_j)\\
              &= (T_B w_i)(v_j)\\
              &= B(v_j, w_i)\\
              &= b_{ji}
\end{align*}
So the matrix of $T_B$ is the transpose of the matrix for $B$, now let us consider $S_B$: We have writing $(\beta_{ij}) = [S_B]_{\mathcal B_V, \mathcal B_W^*}$ for the matrix of $S_B$ with respect to $\mathcal B_V$ and $\mathcal B_W^*$, that
\begin{align*}
  \beta_{ij} &= \sum_k \beta_{ik} w_k^*(w_j)\\
             &= (S_B v_i)(w_j)\\ 
             &= B(v_i, w_j)\\
             &= b_{ij}
\end{align*}
So we have $[T_B]_{\mathcal B_W^*, \mathcal B_V} = [S_B]_{\mathcal B_V^*, \mathcal B_W}^t$, and as a matrix and its transpose have the same rank, so do $S_B$ and $T_B$.

Comment: Thank u very much, but I think u confused and the matrix represent S is the transpose matrix and not T, correct me if I am wrong. Anyway again, thank u very much !!

Comment: So, am I wrong ?